# Creating New Table From Resultant Table Where Each Row Is the Sum Of All the Values Before It

Tags: statistics, mysql-workbench, metrics

I'm trying to create a table that can be used to make a saturation graph. From my current database, I can currently output how many statements and insights come from each specific source, and I have put them in descending order of number of statements. Below is an example of the table I have been able to output:

[Picture of Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iptc.png)

However, in order to get a table that can be input to software to make a saturation graph, I need to make a new table from this one where each row is the sum of all the values in the row above, and the given row. Based on the picture shared above, I would need to new resultant table to look like this:

| Number of Statements | Number of Insights |
| --- | --- |
| 177 | 177 |
| 281 | 283 |
| 339 | 340 |
| and so on | and so forth |

I tried creating this with a FOR loop, but was unable to get it to work properly. Perhaps there is a command for this that I am unaware of?